# SMS vs TCP for weak signal GSM-based M2M communications?

Tags: tcp, sms, gsm

I have a remote sensor that talks to the world via a low bandwidth TCP connection over GSM. It can often be in a location with extremely patchy GSM connectivity though.  At the moment, the remote sensor waits for a GPRS network and then initiates a TCP connection with the server and then listens for commands (which are only a dozen or so bytes every hour or so)

Is an SMS more or less likely to get through to the remote sensor than being able complete a TCP connection?  I guess I'm wondering how likely it is that a network signal strength is sufficient for SMS but not for TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard text messaging services for M2M is good idea if you can fit your data in  140 bytes. For short transmissions, opening an GPRS/1xRTT (2G) IP session, transmitting the data to a server and closing the session is less efficient and more likely to go wrong than sending an SMS.

As a side note, you can also use SMS (MT-SMS) to bring IoT device online (mechanism called "Shoulder-Taps" ).

Answer (score 0):

Compared to data (or voice), SMS use only the signaling part of the mobile network. It's a quite cheap operation in terms of network resources reservation so you'll more likely get through with an SMS than with a data connection in a weak signal environment. One additional advantage is much lower power consumption of your terminal which might be important for M2M context.

As stated by @Jarek previously, you need to be able to pack your data into 140 bytes or to forge "long" SMSes which are kind of concatenation of "simple" 140-bytes SMSes